# How to set CurrentRating property of rating control using jquery/javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit, rating

I am using following rating control

```
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="cc1" %>

<cc1:Rating ID="Rating1" AutoPostBack="true" OnChanged="OnRatingChanged" runat="server"
                                    StarCssClass="Star" WaitingStarCssClass="WaitingStar" EmptyStarCssClass="Star"
                                    FilledStarCssClass="FilledStar">
                                </cc1:Rating>
```

How to set CurrentRating property of using jquery/javascript.
I am getting rating value from a WebService

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I'd advice to add attribute `ClientIdMode=Static` to your rating control.

Now, each value in the rating control has a unique id, for example for a rating control with id `Rating1`, score 1 should have an id like `Rating1_Star_1`.

In your case, an active star in the rating has class `Star Star` (I would use different CSS clases for attributes `StarCssClass` and `EmptyStarCssClass` btw)

Based on the return value from your webservice you could then loop through the results, something like:

`for(i=0;i++;i< valuefromyourwebservice){
  $('#Rating1Star_Star_' + i).attr('class','Star StarOn'); 
}`

Be sure to check the on/off values for the rating values from your browser inspector to see the exact class names.